# Random disappearance of a picture in a set of pictures

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint-2010

I'm looping through an object of objects to get the employees by hire year and display their portrait and name. This is a custom html/javascript file I've added to a SharePoint website content editor web part.

```
var classes = { 
2013: { 
"image/path.png" : "name of employee", 
"image/path2.png" : "name of employee2" 
}, 
2012... 
}
```

I'm using the following jQuery to load the images

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('li').on('mouseover', function(e){
                $('#overlay').empty();
                var title = $('<h2>');
                title.text('Class of ' +  e.target.id);
                $('#overlay').append(title);

                $.each(classes[e.target.id], function(k, v) {
                    var img = $('<img/>');
                    img.attr('src', k);
                    var $imgContainer = $("<span class='imagesContainer'>");
                    $imgContainer.append(img);
                    $imgContainer.append("<span class='names'>" + v + "</span>");
                    $('#overlay').append($imgContainer);
                }); 
            });
        });
```

And HTML to display:

```
    <ul id="classes">
        <br>
        <li id="2013">Class of 2013</li>
        <li id="2014">Class of 2014</li>
        <li id="2015">Class of 2015</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="overlay"></div>
```

**Issues:**

1) When I hover over the Class Years link, it displays all the portraits and names, however sometimes not all the images in `var classes = {` object are displayed. It seems like sometimes not all of them load. For example, Class of 2013 has 7 images in the object, so the jQuery `$.each` function should load all 7 images, but sometimes only 6 or 5 appear.

2) The images do not display at all on IE8. When I hover over the classes, only the title "Class of 20XX" appears, and no images/names. I don't think it's a jQuery version issue.

---

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/k6PcG/11/)

Comment: could you provide a fiddle or demo page?

Comment: have you seen http://placekitten.com/ ...  just for this purpose.

Comment: @andi AWWW KITTENS! Lol, anyway I've updated the fiddle. Thanks! It seems there are no missing images from the fiddle, but on the SharePoint site there are. And I couldn't test on IE 8 because crappy IE 8 doesn't even support fiddle.

Comment: yeah, figures.  When problems only /sometimes/ happen, it's usually not a problem with the front-end code (unless it's asychronous JS).  Something else is causing your first problem.

Comment: in your object, you are using the image source as the key and the name as value, is it possible that you have the same image source for many employees? (like a default image or something?) because, in that case: only the last one will get fetched.

Comment: @avrahamcool good thought, but all of my image paths/sources are different.